# downloading file through a file's path stored in database in jsp

Tags: jsp, hyperlink

hi want to download a file from a directory where the file location is stored in a database,i have done the coding for retrieving the path from database to a html table,but i dont know hoe to download the file using its path stored in database.here is my code for retrieving the path from database.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*"%>


 <%
 String id=request.getParameter("id");
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksa","root","root");  
 Statement st=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select id,file_path,file_date from file12 where id like '"+id+"%'");
 %>
 <table cellpadding="15" border="1">
 <%
 while(rs.next()){

%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString("id")%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString("file_path")%></td> 

 <td><%=rs.getString("file_date")%> </td> 
  </tr>
  <%}%>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><a href = '<%=rs.getString("file_path")%>'><%=rs.getString("file_path")%></a></td>
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Then you probably need to prepend the correct path to your filename, eg. if your file_path evaluates to 'bar.txt' and this file is found at http://example.com/foo/bar.txt, you need to write <a href = '/foo/<%=rs.getString("file_path")%>'>